# Usage of "so" in "so I think it is a great way to spend quality time"

Tags: expressions

The sentence goes like this..

> I'm busy because of my work so I don't have much time to communicate with my family. To make it up, I think it is a great way to spend quality time.

I think the quoted phrase seems so unnatural so I want to rephrase to be more natural...
Should I just use "so" at the beginning of the second sentence, like "so I think it is a great way..."?

Could you give me some better expression to connect those sentences?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to just using "So...", one stylistic issue is repetition; you've already used "so" in the first sentence. Not a major felony, but often better avoided.

Options I might consider include:

> In light of that...
>
> Because of that...
>
> As a result...
>
> Under the circumstances...

There is another possible problem, arising from what I'd say is some imprecision in your overall language, and especially in how the second sentence relates to the first. But it's a bit beyond the scope of your original question (although it is another reason why a "So" connecting phrase might not be best), so I'll leave it unless you want to hear more. (I know that sounds like a tease, but it's really not! :-) )